# Spring boot - Messaging with RabbitMQ to listen message queue continuously

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue

When I run the Messaging with RabbitMQ guide [I tried this demo application][1] , the listener only receive the message once (**the runner send once and then exited**). I hope the listener can continuously listen the message queue, how should I achieve it ?

the receiver code:

```
    package hello;

    import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class Receiver {

      private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

      public void receiveMessage(String message) {
          System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
          latch.countDown();
      }

      public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
          return latch;
      }

  }
```

the runner code:

```
    package hello;

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
    import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

        private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
        private final Receiver receiver;

        public Runner(Receiver receiver, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
            this.receiver = receiver;
            this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Sending message...");
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Application.topicExchangeName, "foo.bar.baz", "====1===========Hello from RabbitMQ!");
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Application.topicExchangeName, "foo.bar.baz", "====2===========Hello from RabbitMQ!");
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Application.topicExchangeName, "foo.bar.baz", "=====3==========Hello from RabbitMQ!");
            receiver.getLatch().await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }

    }
```

the application code:

```
ackage hello;

    import hello.test.TestListener;
    import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
    import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
    import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
    import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
    import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
    import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
    import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

        static final String topicExchangeName = "spring-boot-exchange";

        public static final String queueName = "spring-boot";

        @Bean
        Queue queue() {
            return new Queue(queueName, false);
        }

        @Bean
        TopicExchange exchange() {
            return new TopicExchange(topicExchangeName);
        }

        @Bean
        Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
            return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("foo.bar.#");
        }

        @Bean
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            container.setQueueNames(queueName);
            container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
            return container;
        }

        @Bean
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
            return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args).close();
        }

    }
```

the log

```
    [opuser@iZ25fprd8a9Z java]$ java -jar gs-messaging-rabbitmq-0.1.0.jar 

      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.1.RELEASE)

    2019-01-10 09:40:53.846  INFO 412 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on iZ25fprd8a9Z with PID 412 (/data/workspace/test/java/gs-messaging-rabbitmq-0.1.0.jar started by opuser in /data/workspace/test/java)
    2019-01-10 09:40:53.854  INFO 412 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2019-01-10 09:40:55.019  INFO 412 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$870d6481] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2019-01-10 09:40:56.047  INFO 412 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [10.171.135.109:5672]
    2019-01-10 09:40:56.145  INFO 412 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#76f2b07d:0/SimpleConnection@49c43f4e [delegate=amqp://petmq@10.171.135.109:5672/, localPort= 41068]
    2019-01-10 09:40:56.152  INFO 412 --- [           main] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (spring-boot) durable:false, auto-delete:false, exclusive:false. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.
    2019-01-10 09:40:56.244  INFO 412 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Started Application in 3.116 seconds (JVM running for 4.001)
    Sending message...
    Received <====1===========Hello from RabbitMQ!>
    Received <====2===========Hello from RabbitMQ!>
    Received <=====3==========Hello from RabbitMQ!>
    2019-01-10 09:40:56.269  INFO 412 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
    2019-01-10 09:40:57.267  INFO 412 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
    2019-01-10 09:40:57.272  INFO 412 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Shutdown ignored - container is not active already
```

Comment: Is it really related to spring-boot (or related to some configuration / rabbitmq)? Also please edit the post  your `code` used for rabbitmq messaging part.

Comment: I posted the code .why the application not stay there for waiting other msg,but only received the msg by runner send and then exited?

Comment: SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args).close()  well, demo invoke close(),I deleted the invocation,it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you add the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Your application will not close out.